# Batch rename list of files based on other properties?

Tags: image, powershell, file-rename, file-management, batch-rename

I have two folders. Folder A contains high resolution images and folder B low resolution images. Images of Folder B are located in the server. I need to change all images to a  higher resolution version contained in local folder A, **without changing the file name**.

I can upload and replace the images from folder A to folder B via FileZilla but I need before to rename all images with the same name as folder B.

Unfortunately images have custom and unique names. What would be the best path to follow on this specific case?

Comment: How do you link files in both folders? Do they have anything in common, apart from content? Anything like: foo_bar_low.jpg and foo_bar_high.jpg? Without examples it's hard to suggest any solution.

Comment: First, thanks for your answer. No there's nothing in common except the content. File name have this structure: keywordDDMMYY001.jpg, keywordDDMMYY002.jpg for each post.

Comment: If the content is your only matching criteria you need to [calculate the similarity](http://hackerlabs.org/blog/2012/07/30/organizing-photos-with-duplicate-and-similarity-checking/) for each set of two files. I don't think there is a ready-made PowerShell cmdlet or module for this, but perhaps you could cook something up with ImageMagick's [`compare`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/compare.php) utility.

Comment: Is there a correlation between the hi res image filename and the lo res image filename?

Comment: Same images but different resolution.